# filter result value from a promise to my html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have created a custom stateful filter with the following function that call a service that returned a promise:

```
   function functionIDOne(customService) { 
     return function(id) { 
       return customService.getNameById(id).then(function(rslt){
         console.log( rslt.name); 
         return rslt.name;
       }); 
       getNameById.$stateful = true; 
       return getNameById;
     }
   }
```

the issue that i cann't got the returned value in the html because it is in the promise.

Even with stateful filter. How can i did it?

Comment: You can't have two returns in one block. `getNameById` will be never returned.

Comment: so how can i return rslt.name? i am new with angular